# Select Minimum from Group in dataframe if it hasn't been selected in the past year

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm a beginner using pandas in python and I am having trouble selecting some specific data. I have a data frame and I would like to subset the data so that I return the $ticker with the minimum rank *if it has not been the minimum in the last 12 months*.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xojxlPDs6TLoAhNavbudbIP6PxUwr5k58mScstybVQw/edit#gid=0

Does anyone know how I could select where rank == 1 if it is has not been selected within the previous year?

Comment: answered you below.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Zachary Marx updated the solution, check and tell me the result.

Comment: @inquirer in your result there are only `rank==1` while in his desired output there is not necessarily `rank==1`. The goal isn't explained very well imo, if I check the desired output I think he wants to groupby `Date` and get the minimum rank BUT each `$sticker` can only be once the minimum in a year. While equal, take the next smallest rank with its corresponding `$ticker`

Comment: @Rabinzel yesterday Zachary Marx said that rank=1 is needed.

Comment: @inquirer True that. But I think like in the title of the question, he means the minimum

Comment: @Rabinzel several times I came across trolls, no matter how you do it, it will still be wrong. Therefore, there is no desire, without a specific explanation, to do anything. My neighbors, drug addicts, do not allow me to live peacefully here with their noise. Therefore, I do not have much time to calmly think and find the best solution.

Comment: rabinzel is correct in the goal. @inquirer I'm sorry for your situation, hopefully you can think peacefully soon.

Comment: @ZacharyMarx I don't think this will ever happen as long as I live here. This has been going on for 9 fucking years. I posted both options for rank==1 and for all data (it turned out with a cycle, and it will be long if there is a lot of data. It was enough for me).

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

date_ind = pd.read_csv('df3.txt', sep=',', header=0)
date_ind['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(date_ind['Date'])
date_ind = date_ind.set_index('Date')

df = date_ind[date_ind["rank"] == 1]

def func_data(x):
    time_year = x.index + pd.DateOffset(years=-1)
    time_day = x.index + pd.DateOffset(days=-1)
    ticker = x['$ticker'][0]
    aaa = date_ind[(date_ind.index <= time_day[0]) & (date_ind.index >= time_year[0]) & (date_ind["rank"] == 1) &
                   (df['$ticker'] == ticker)]

    if len(aaa) <= 0:
        return df.loc[x.index]

new = df.groupby(['Date']).apply(func_data).dropna()

print(new)
```

If all data is needed:

```
import pandas as pd

date_ind = pd.read_csv('df3.txt', sep=',', header=0)
date_ind['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(date_ind['Date'])
date_ind = date_ind.reset_index()

qqq = []
for i in range(0, len(date_ind)):
    time_year = date_ind.loc[i, 'Date'] - pd.DateOffset(years=1)
    time_day = date_ind.loc[i, 'Date'] - pd.DateOffset(days=1)
    ticker = date_ind.loc[i, '$ticker']
    rank = date_ind.loc[i, 'rank']
    aaa = date_ind[(date_ind['Date'] <= time_day) & (date_ind['Date'] >= time_year) & (date_ind["rank"] == rank)
                   & (date_ind['$ticker'] == ticker)]
    if len(aaa) <= 0:
        bbb = date_ind.loc[i, :]
        qqq.append(bbb.values)


df = pd.DataFrame(qqq)
df = df.set_axis(date_ind.columns, axis=1, inplace=False)
print(df)
```

Comment: Thank you! this works for one month, but what if I have a list of 120 months I need to filter through? Would this require a for loop?

Comment: Should have said so right away. And show all possible options.

Comment: Sorry about that, this is my first ever stack overflow post.

Comment: I foresee another problem, you will have a value last year, next year it means there will be no value and subsequent ...?

Comment: There will always be another option. The list each month is very long I just pasted a bit of it because it would've been too big.

Comment: Let's do it, I'm tired of guessing. You keep stock APPL share. Make more data with it over several years. And show the expected result.

Comment: Ok I've added a google sheet into the initial question which shows both the starting dataframe and the expected output